# SQLite database become blank when I run my project in simulator other then iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, sqlite

There is `UITableView` in my `ViewController` that becomes empty when I run it in  iPhone 4s simulator but it loads when I run it on iPhone 5s.
When I check the database, it becomes blank when I run the project in iPhone 4s or 6s simulator. The data is in `UITableView`.

[output in other then 5s simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaiuk.png)

[output in 5s simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHRK0.png)

Comment: Where does the database come from?

Comment: @Hardik Patel. Provide more info

Comment: @Hardik Patel when you will run your project first in simulator(let's assume 5s) it will create database.After that if u will run your project in another simulator(assume 6s) it will create new database after adding value in database if u run it again in this simulator it will show data.So,conclusion is every simulator will have its "Personal" database so each simulator will create database one time.

Comment: You should provide more details such as when and how is the database gets created.

Comment: bhavin i tried it,, It works,, thanks